# Phoenix umbrella compile order

Tags: macros, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an umbrella project with 3 apps: `main_web`, `main` and `child`.

I have a macro defined in `main` which the `child` app uses.

When compiling, I sometimes get an error saying that `Main.MyMacro` is not defined in `some_file_in_child_app.ex` when I run the same command again, everything is fine.

I think this is from `some_file_in_child_app.ex` trying to use the macro before it has been compiled.

What is a good way to go about ensuring `Main.MyMacro` is loaded and so that I can avoid this error?

I'm not sure if going down the lines of running `mix compile apps/main` is the right way to go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have dependencies between your umbrella applications, you need to explicitly list them.

You should add this to `apps/child/mix.exs`:

```
def deps do
  [
    # ... other deps ...
    {:main, in_umbrella: true}
  ]
end
```

Now Mix will make sure to compile `main` before compiling `child`.